# Angular Strap typeahead popover displaying in wrong position

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-strap

I am using angular-strap 2.3.9. And using following code for bootstrap typeahead:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="list" bs-options="val.description as val.description for val in listValues" ng-blur="checkFunction()" limit="10" bs-typeahead>
```

When I type the first character in the text box, the popover appears in the right bottom of the screen (screenshot 1 - typeaheadIssue). But for the second character on wards, the popover displays correctly below the text box (screenshot 2 - typeaheadIssue1).

I have tried using angular-strap 2.2.4 which works fine, but angular-strap 2.3.8 creates this issue. Is this an open issue or any update has been released with this fix?

Please check the attached screen shots for the reference:

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Comment: It's seems to be a CSS problem. Have you checked `min-width` property of the bootstrap `.dropdown-menu` class? Can you share a little bit more of your code (At least HTML parents elements and relevant CSS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced angular strap typeahead as follows:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="list" typeahead="val.description as val.description for val in valueListValues | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10" ng-blur="checkFunction()" >
```

It solved the issue.